# How can i show dialog boxes after each other dynamically?

Tags: android

I'm a noob programmer currently making an android application which is a risk-assessment "checklist". I want to use Dialogues to show the questions and then let the user press yes or no.

QUESTION: Is it possible to dynamically generate a dialog box after one-another without having to make a dialog method for all 49 questions? Like having only 1 method for the dialog box but make it show different question when the user press the YES button.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. And it is the correct way to do that.

Comment: But how do i do that? :)

Comment: There are many ways to do that. You could use a DialogFrament, for example, and re-use that one again and again - It could contain a quetion in its title and a list of radiobuttons with the possible answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible,

You can create create dialog method and in that method you can ask questions.In dialog it ask question from string array and in while loop. while loop break when your question is finished. Like this:

```
String [] question_desc=new String [100]// if you have 100 question
question_desc[0]="xx";
question_desc[1]="yy";
.....
//Then in while
int counter=0;
while(question_desc.length)
{
call_create_dialog_method(question_desc[counter]);
counter++;
}

//then

public void call_create_dialog_method(String description)
{
 AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

                alert.setTitle("Q&A");
                alert.setMessage(description);

                // Set an EditText view to get user input 
                final EditText input = new EditText(this);
                alert.setView(input);

                alert.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        //you can do what you need
                  }
                });
        //set negative button and consequent action according to your requirment
                alert.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    // Canceled.
                  }
                });

                alert.show();  
}
```

Comment: I have another dilemma with my coding; Some questions are suppose to trigger another dialogbox where the user must grade a risk.

Like this: question: Did you switch off the power? Yes - No?  if "NO" is selected, a dialog with risk assessment is called. This dialog must be able to be called on YES answers as well, depending on what kind of question it is. Like this: Question 1 calls on the risk-grading dialog on button YES.  Question 2 calls on the risk-grading dialog on button NO.

Comment: There will be two dialog methods. One for the questions where the user selects YES or NO. The 2:nd method allow user write in two edittext fields and a dropdown where he selects a risk-grade: High, medium, low. The 2:nd dialog method is supposed to be bound to a question. I don't know if this answers your question :p

Comment: so you can create two methods like **call_create_dialog_method1** and **call_create_dialog_method2** then in *while* loop you should put **if** condition to detect

Answer (score 3):

```
create method and call each time by passing question

public void showAlertDialog(String question){

AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);  
alertDialog.setTitle("Title");  
alertDialog.setMessage(question);  
 alertDialog.setButton("OK", null);  
 AlertDialog alert = alertDialog.create();
alert.show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do that is an Alert Dialog method, to show sequential popup, the conditions and code for consecutive popup(s) would have to be reachable from one to the other.
AlertDialog1 has to contain the code which would show AlertDialog2...

Try something like this:

```
                AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

                alert.setTitle("Title");
                alert.setMessage("Your Question");

                // Set an EditText view to get user input 
                final EditText input = new EditText(this);
                alert.setView(input);

                alert.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {


                    //assess input
                 //call function for next dialog
                        callNextDialog(pass question parameter here);
                  }
                });
        //set negative button and consequent action according to your requirment
                alert.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    // Canceled.
                  }
                });

                alert.show();
```

Put that in a method and call that method setting parameters for your question, depending on your implementation.

Question parameter can be an Id which can be set incrementally...